# Variable in an array: required, a good practice, or redundant?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it a good idea to put a JavaScript variable into an array?
Here's a sample code:

```
var foo = ['<p>Hello, world!</p>'];
var myBlob = new Blob(foo, {type: 'text/html'});
```

vs.

```
var foo = '<p>Hello, world!</p>';
var myBlob = new Blob([foo], {type: 'text/html'});
```

Comment: Note that you never put a *variable* into an array in JavaScript. You put the value that the variable contains in the array, not the variable.

Comment: That is not just "a bracket" in this case but as [Blob constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob) expects an array as its first parameter, it is a literal array declaration. So yes, it is required.

Comment: Your question isn't really about putting a variable into an array, but rather about the use of the Blob object. The documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob says that your first example is the appropriate way to use it. You're creating a new object and passing the variable as an argument to the constructor, you don't put it into an array.

Comment: For your example there is no difference unless you use `foo` somewhere else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two examples do exactly the same thing, other than that `foo` will end up with a different value at the end; it makes no difference to the blob at all. It doesn't matter which you use, neither is best practice more than the other. It depends on what you want to do with `foo` afterward (e.g., do you want it to refer to an array with a string in it, or to a string).

Note that you never put a *variable* into an array in JavaScript. You put the value that the variable contains in the array, not the variable.

So with your first example, you create an array with the string in it, refer to that array with `foo`, and then pass a copy of that reference into the `Blob` constructor.

In your second example, you put the string in `foo` (effectively), and then create an array with that string and pass it into the `Blob` constructor.

It comes to the same thing in the end as far as the blob is concerned. The only difference is what you have in `foo` afterward.

Comment: What happens if I use `foo` afterward? How does it make a difference?

Comment: @Hermes: Poor wording on my part. The only difference it makes is that in your first example, `foo` refers to an array with a string in it, and in your second example `foo` refers to a string. So it just changes how you might use `foo` afterward. Nothing you do with `foo` after the `new Blob` line will have any effect on the blob.

Answer (score -1):

In JavaScript `[]` is an array, a comma-separated collection.

```
var i = 1;

Object.prototype.toString.call( i ); // [object Number]
Object.prototype.toString.call( [i] ); // [object Array]
```

Putting square brackets around a variable means something completely different from on it being on its own.

Comment: "a comma-separated collection" --- :-S